# Unity 2D: How to confirm if specific amount of coins had been collected before loading to next level?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I get the number of coins collected in CoinPicker script and access it in LevelLoader script?
Here is my CoinPicker script:

```
 public class CoinPicker : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public float coin = 0;
     public TextMeshProUGUI textCoins;
     
     
     private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
     {
         if (other.transform.tag == "Coins")
         {
             coin++;
             textCoins.text = coin.ToString();
             Destroy(other.gameObject);
         }
     }
 
     
 }
```

Here is my LevelLoader script:

```
public class LevelLoader : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public int iLevelToLoad;
     public string sLevelToLoad;
     public bool useIntegerToLoadLevel;
 
     private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
     {
         GameObject collisionGameObject = collision.gameObject;
 
         if(collisionGameObject.gameObject.tag == "Player" )
         {
             LoadScene();
         }
     }
     
     void LoadScene()
     {
         if(useIntegerToLoadLevel)
         {
             SceneManager.LoadScene(iLevelToLoad);
         }
         else
         {
             SceneManager.LoadScene(sLevelToLoad);
         }
     }
 }
```

Please help, I am weak at this :(

Comment: Simply reference the `CoinPicker` in the `LevelLoader` script .. either via a field in the Inspector or e.g. `FindObjectOfType` etc .. then you have direct access to its public fields

Answer (score 1):

You can make a get direct from Coin picker and get from level loader access the coin from CoinPicker.

```
public class LevelLoader : MonoBehaviour
{
     public CoinPicker CoinPicker;
     public int iLevelToLoad;
     public string sLevelToLoad;
     public bool useIntegerToLoadLevel;

     private void Start()
     {
       Debug.log(CoinPicker.coin); //you can get coin from here
     }
 
     private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
     {
         GameObject collisionGameObject = collision.gameObject;
 
         if(collisionGameObject.gameObject.tag == "Player" )
         {
             LoadScene();
         }
     }
     
     void LoadScene()
     {
         if(useIntegerToLoadLevel)
         {
             SceneManager.LoadScene(iLevelToLoad);
         }
         else
         {
             SceneManager.LoadScene(sLevelToLoad);
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the same TextMesh you used in the Collision script. You would just put

```
public TextMeshProUGUI textCoins;
```

in the field of the second one, so that textCoins.text is the number of coins you collected. Then drag the same TextMesh into the TextMesh box in the Unity editor.

I can't tell what you are using the coins for in the Level loader, but if you wanted to check the number of coins that you collected, you would just say

```
if(int.Parse(textCoins.text) == RequiredNumberOfCoins)
```

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: If you anyway rely on a shared reference why not rather directly have a reference to the `CoinPicker` script like suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68706985/7111561)? Going via string parsing here is quite unnecessary, slow and error prone (e.g. If OP later doesn't want to only display the raw number but something like e.g. `"Coins: " + coin`)